# Why do some SE sites have a quorum badge on their meta page?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, badges, per-site-meta

I'm thinking specifically of the great outdoors, where [the meta page](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/badges) shows the quorum badge (and the similar convention badge.)

Is this a bug or is there something I'm missing? I can't see any good reason why they should be there, especially since on other sites (such as meta SO) they're not present.

EDIT: From the comment perhaps it's a bug that effects only beta sites?

Comment: Music (public beta) doesn't have one either, looks like maybe the private beta stuff never had it removed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have removed the Quorum and Convention badges from site metas.