# Beta badges on beta metas - award or remove?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, beta-badge

[Outdoors](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com) just came out of beta and everyone (who earned it) got their beta badges. And the quorum and convention badges disappeared from meta, [as they should](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120850/172958).  But I noticed that there were no beta badges awarded on meta.outdoors (yes, there were at least a few people who had the activity to earn them), but [the badge is still there](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta). I checked and sure enough, [it was there (unearned) on SFF too](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/16/beta).  If it cannot be earned on meta, it should be removed as the quorum and convention badges were. On the other hand, I think it could be good to keep it and give it to those whose meta activity was enough to earn it, so as to indicate who had an interest in driving the site as it was first getting started.

Answer (score 3):

These badges have all been removed.